# array_merge strange behaviour

Tags: php, arrays

Look at this code:

```
$a = array('1'=>'1');
$b = array(''=>'');

var_dump(array_merge($a,$b));
```

the output seems really strange to me:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(1) "1"
  '' =>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Ok, I've changed `$a` into this: `$a = array('k'=>'v');` and the output became more predictable:

```
array(2) {
  'k' =>
  string(1) "v"
  '' =>
  string(0) ""
}
```

The question is: why the hell the key of the first element is `0` in the first example?

**edit:**

```
var_dump($a);
array(1) {
  [1] =>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

Comment: numeric keys will be renumbered!

Comment: *Hint:* What does `var_dump($a)` give?

Comment: @hakre, inserted into question. Yes, I know that the first '1' is treated as a number...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array.
>
> http://php.net/array_merge

Yes, it's an idiosyncrasy of PHP to treat numeric string values as numeric values in this case. You may want to use `$a + $b` instead.

Comment: thanks! actually I'm already using `+`, I'va just wanted to get an explanation